# Facing Error in WordPress Custom Post

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-rest-api

I'm facing issue in custom post type I write code of wordpress custom post type everything working fine but I want to make global code to call everywhere. But when I'm trying to make 2 different files to make code global then showing error "500 error"

Here is code

```
    $custom_terms = get_field('portfolio_gallery_category_name');
print_r(get_field('portfolio_gallery_category_name'));

foreach($custom_terms as $custom_term):
    wp_reset_query();
    $args = array('post_type' => 'portfolio',
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'portfolio_type',
                'field' => 'term_id',
                'terms' => $custom_term->term_id,
            ),
        ),
     );
$loop = new WP_Query($args);
include('templates-sections/portfolios.php');
```

and the other remaining code in other global file name is templates-sections/portfolios.php

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);

 if($loop->have_posts()): ?>

    <?php while($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();
            ?>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 p-0 scale-anm" data-aos="fade-zoom">
            <a href="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url('full'); ?>" data-toggle="lightbox" data-gallery="example-gallery">
            <img src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url('full'); ?>" class="img-responsive" /></a>
        </div>
      <?php endwhile; ?>
     <?php endif; ?>
<? endforeach; ?>
```

I've on all errors reporting but same thing showing "500" error can anyone help to resolve this issue.

I know lots of peoples have solutions and someone resolve this minor issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A 500 error is a generic error message and covers pretty much every single thing that can go wrong with a script. Check your server error logs to find out the exact error message.

Comment: You probably can't defer a foreach loop in two files. Don't start it in 1 file and end it in the other.

Comment: What about combining the 02 files into one, or just use $loop = new WP_Query($args); inside the portfolios.php

Comment: @BassemRabia I tried and move $loop = new WP_Query($args);  but same error or white blank page...

Comment: Have any solution to divide foreach loop in 2 files.

Comment: Don't. Add the end of the foreach loop into your first file, after your include. This may not be the issue, however. **Check your server error logs for more information about the error message.**

Comment: I am not sure but this line can be the main source of your problem
<? endforeach; ?> php tag is missing <?php endforeach; ?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a function in your second file and call it in your first file.

```
<?php

$custom_terms = get_field('portfolio_gallery_category_name');
print_r(get_field('portfolio_gallery_category_name'));

include('templates-sections/portfolios.php');

foreach($custom_terms as $custom_term):
    wp_reset_query();
    $args = array('post_type' => 'portfolio',
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'portfolio_type',
                'field' => 'term_id',
                'terms' => $custom_term->term_id,
            ),
        ),
    );

$loop = new WP_Query($args);

myFunction( $loop );

endforeach;

?>
```

Your second file

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);

function myFunction( $loop ) {
    if($loop->have_posts()): 

        while($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();
           ?>
           <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 p-0 scale-anm" data-aos="fade-zoom">
              <a href="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url('full'); ?>" data-toggle="lightbox" data-gallery="example-gallery">
                 <img src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url('full'); ?>" class="img-responsive" /></a>
             </div>
         <?php endwhile;
     endif;

 }


 ?>
```